# How to instantiate class with different arguments

Tags: c++

I need a way to calculate various types of anomalies in a dataset. hence, i was thinking of having a generic Anomaly interface, which defines the interface for concrete Anomalies. Then my application can simply use the interface to iterate over various concrete strategies.

The main problem i am running into is that the construction of concrete Anomalies requires different inputs. For example,

```
class Anamoly
{
public:
  template <typename T> 
  virtual Anamoly * getInstance(T &) = 0;
  virtual void processAnamoly() = 0;
  virtual bool containsAnamoly() = 0;
  virtual void logAnamoly() = 0;
};
```

Since templates functions cannot be virtual, is there a way to get around this issue, which would allow construction of concrete Anomalies with different inputs, yet, allow me to use the generic interface for rest of the behavior?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why `getInstance` is a member function, and virtual. Sounds like it should be a separate factory function or factory class, and then, I suppose, there would be no need for it to be virtual. The class hierarchy of anomalies isn't really related to how they are generated, or is it?

Comment: You are right that the problem can be solved by separate factory class, but i was trying to minimize number of classes required.

Comment: Ok. Let me just say that minimizing the number of classes is a questionable ambition to have (because it doesn't help code readability, nor performance). Also, keep in mind that a separate class or function doesn't necessarily require a separate file in C++. You could put a nice and clean factory function in a namespace defined in the same file, or even as a static function of the `Anomaly` base class.

Comment: You can look into factory method design pattern implementation.

Comment: make static member functions(factory method) for every concrete Anomalies, which return pointers to the abstract Anamoly.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual function with templates parameters isn't going to work, but you could use a static template function:

```
class Anomaly {
public:
  template <typename T> 
  static Anomaly * getInstance(T &);
  virtual void processAnamoly() = 0;
  virtual bool containsAnamoly() = 0;
  virtual void logAnamoly() = 0;
};
```

Then, whenever you define a relevant subclass, implement `Anomaly::getInstance()`, such as in `myanomaly.cpp`:

```
class MyAnomaly : public Anomaly {
  // implement virtual functions
};

Anomaly * Anomaly::getInstance(MyType & t) {
  return new MyAnomaly(t);
};
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to touch the `anomaly.h` header file whenever you add a new class, and you don't need to expose subclasses outside of their definition file. The downside is type errors get only caught at link time and not at compile time.